# How to access stack frame while debugging ASP.net program?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

How to access stack frame information while debugging ASP.net program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're referring the ["Call Stack" window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3694ts5.aspx), you can view that *when debugging* by opening the Call Stack Window using either it's default hotkey of `CTRL+ALT+C`, or by using the IDE menu of
`Debug / Windows / Call Stack`

Alternatively, if you're referring to [ASP.NET's built-in Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420.aspx) capability, whereby the ASP.NET runtime will display diagnostic information about a single request for an ASP.NET page, you can achieve this on a *per page* basis by adding `Trace="true"` to the `Page` directive at the top of the specific page

For example:

```
<%@ Page Trace="true" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>
```

or you can [achieve ASP.NET tracing application-wide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y89ed7z%28v=VS.71%29.aspx), by adding the `<trace>` directive to the `<system.web>` section of the `web.config` file.  I.e.

```
<system.web>
  <trace enabled="true"/>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that  whether in  page directive or  web.config :

in page directive (in aspx file ) just add Trace="true" 
Or you can do that in web.config for all the pages

```
<trace enabled="true" pageOutput="true" requestLimit="10" traceMode="SortByTime" localOnly="true" />
```

enabled property turns tracing on or off

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

At page level you can do that with the help of

<%@ Page Trace="true".....................................

or you can also enable it from the codebehind in the page load method as 
            Trace.Enabled = true;

Is this what you are looking for?

or you can try this link
http://peterkellner.net/2009/12/21/how-to-get-a-stack-trace-from-c-without-throwing-exception/