# ASP.NET event call stack or event source

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an ASP.NET page, I have datetime pickers and other drop down lists, on selection change of drop down lists the datetime textchanged events get fired. 
However nothing is calling the events explicitly and there are no changes on the datetime pickers text that are causing the events to fire.

[UPDATE] - It seems this is happening only with the first DDL selection change event, the next time the datetime picker event doesn't get fired.

How can I know who is calling it? Is there some call stack for asp.net events?

Comment: You can probably get stack trace information with `new StackTrace(int).GetFrame(int)` and tweak the `int` values to find the caller.  Events also have a `sender` object you can inspect which should be whatever triggered the event.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding what you mean...but the DDL component is what fires the event based on the user clicking a new item. If you inspect the `sender` parameter you should find it's a reference to the DDL.

Comment: @David the sender object points to the datetime picker which I can't find who changed its value.

Comment: @James before the DDL event is called, the datetime picker is being fired. that's my problem. who fired it?

Comment: What component are you using?

Comment: My assumption is that the dateTime pickers have AutoPostBack set to false while the DDL has AutoPostBack set to True.... so when you change the DateTime pickers, no event is fired, but as soon as you change the DDL value, the postback is caused and all the pending events are raised.

Comment: What sort of date time picker is it?  Maybe there's some JavaScript which *always* sets the value of some underlying element (maybe a hidden element?) and ASP.NET is interpreting that as always being a new value?

Comment: @ManishDalal, no its AutoPostBack is set to true. But i noticed now that this event is being fired only with the first event. the next time I change the DDL selection, it doesn't get fired.

Comment: I searched the name of the datetime picker in the whole page including the javascript that may be updating the value, but nothing...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access stack frame while debugging ASP.net program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361524/how-to-access-stack-frame-while-debugging-asp-net-program)

Comment: Also [How to: Use the Call Stack Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3694ts5.aspx)

Comment: Thank you @Liam, i will read the articles now, but meanwhile i just found out that when i comment the ajaxtoolkit:MaskedEditExtender tag for the datetime picker the event doesn't get fired.  <ajaxtoolkit:MaskedEditExtender ID="meeDateFrom" runat="server" Enabled="True" ErrorTooltipEnabled="True" Mask="99/99/9999" MaskType="Date" TargetControlID="txtDateFrom"></ajaxtoolkit:MaskedEditExtender>